# JavaScript .focusout()

Tags: javascript, html, click, onblur

I want to make an alternative select-box. Does anyone know, how I can hide the `<ul>`, if there is a mouse click outside of the list-element? (without jquery and "onblur" does not support mouse clicks, that are not targeted on a specific element)

Comment: the `blur` event is not jQuery specific. It is a [standard event that all browsers should recognize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur).

Comment: @Lix: I think maybe he's saying that a click won't trigger the blur event, so he can't trigger the Js by leaving the list like he could with an `input`.

Comment: @Entimon: Bind a click handler to the `document` that checks to see if the click took place outside your `ul`.

Comment: Essentially, once your element is in it's "open" state, a click anywhere on the document (that is not one of your elements) would close the select element... So you might be able to listen for a click on the document object.

Comment: ...or, incorporate a hidden `input` into your custom list that gets focus when entering the list, then bind a `blur` handler to that. Or try both to be safe.

Comment: @cookiemonster How can I check, if the element was NOT clicked? Is there an oppositeof the `onclick` Event?

Comment: Bind another handler to the list container that calls `event.stopPropagation()`. This prevents the event from bubbling up any further ensuring that the handler on the `document` is not invoked. So when the `document` handler *is* invoked, we know it was because the click was outside the list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This worked for me:

```
input.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
    //Your code to hide <ul>
}, true);
```

Changing `blur` to:

- `onfocusin` Triggers when the element is focussed for the first time.
- `onfocusout` Triggers when the focus leaves the element (almost the same as `blur`)
- `focus` Triggers when the element is focussed.

Should also trigger the events they describe. I hope this might help you.